# Enum seems to be branching differently for unknown reasons

Tags: vb.net, enums, boolean

Please read my question *carefully*. You are about to see a chunk of most likely very bad logic.

```
Dim num As Boolean
Select Case MyFoo
   Case MyFoo.num
      num = True
   Case Else
      num = False
End Select
```

My question is: Is there any *possible* way for this case statement to branch differently depending on environment, or build options, or etc....    I don't mean it branches randomly, but one environment sees it always branching to Case Else, and another environment always sees it branching to Case MyFoo.num

Build options/switches, Optimization rules, Environment settings, etc...

edit - Assume my object looks like this:

```
Public Enum MyFoo
   word = 1
   otherword = 2
   num = 3
   blahblah = 4
End Enum
```

Comment: So you cannot change it to `Dim num As Boolean = MyFoo = MyFoo.num`?

Comment: I don't follow your question.

Comment: That's the one-liner which replaces the whole `Select...Case`.

Comment: My concern is why this Select Case is seemingly branching differently in different environments, despite running the exact same code using the exact same DB. I'm not sure what your one-liner is saying here. Keep in mind I am new to VB/VB.net

Comment: `MyFoo = MyFoo.num` returns a `Boolean`, it is a comparison of the variable `MyFoo` and the enum `MyFoo.num`(btw, bad naming). So if `MyFoo` **is**  `MyFoo.num` it returns `True`. This `Boolean` is then assigned to the variable `num`. So the same as the `Select...Case` but shorter and more readable. In VB.NET it is not as readable as in C# since both assignments and comparisons use the `=` as operator (in C# it would be `bool num = MyFoo == MyFoo.num;`).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible way for this case statement to branch differently depending on environment, or build options, or etc....

The only way this will branch differently is if there is a different value stored within the `MyFoo` variable in your `Select Case` statement.  The environment should not change the branching logic.

That being said, you never show the code that sets `MyFoo`.  It is possible that the variable is being set differently based on some environmental setting, which could cause you to see this behavior.

Comment: @user2040277 I mean the variable `MyFoo`, not the type, used here: `Select Case MyFoo`

Comment: I'm not to familiar with VB, and that object is being passed in (this is part of a Subroutine). What kind of code would change it?

Comment: @user2040277 Whatever is passing it in... The only way you'll get different branching here is that variable is different when it's passed into your Sub

Comment: Oh, I may have left an important bit out. the MyFoo variable being passed in looks like this:  ByVal MyFoo As SomeObj.MyFoo  which is an enum with 4 hard coded options in it. Does that help clarify?

Comment: @user2040277 My point is that it's not your code - its the code that's passing in the variable to this.  The only reason this will branch differently is if you get a differnet value for your argument

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional compilation

```
Dim num as boolean
#if myfoo
    Num = true
#else
    Num = false
#end if
```

You can then declare the myfoo constant in the project options for that build enviroment

Comment: This might be useful for debugging. What would I put in the project options section to set the value?

Comment: In the compile section (under advanced compiler options) it lets you define compiler constants. This then checks if these are defined.

Comment: @user2040277 If you use it for debuging it is worth knowing VB.Net defines DEBUG on any debug builds and you can dfine symobls for a single file with #const.